# Need help for making a .app file on MacOS

Tags: macos, .app

I have a shell script for My Mac M1 with libraries and an icon separately and I wanted to know if I could convert this into an .app file.
I already tried to make my own .app executable with appify ( https://github.com/machinebox/appify ) or by building the .app folder myself (*.app/Content/MacOS) but when I share it with someone else, apple tells him that the app is broken and we need to run some commands to make it work again.

The commands that solve the problem, but that I no longer want to type every time are:

- sudo spctl --master-disable
- sudo chmod -R 777 *.app
- xattr -d com.apple.quarantine *.app
- xattr -cr *.app

Could someone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: (*.app/Content/MacOS) should be Contents

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html have you consumed and understood this document yet?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know that is Contents that's just a mistake but your second link is useful and I will try to make my own Info.plist file. I think this is the problem. On the site it is written that it is required whereas I botched it without really paying attention. If you ever have any advice to help me make this file, I'm interested

Comment: Info.plist is probably the thing you need to craft... it is the document that tells launch services how to run your app.